# Summarized data between row labels in PowerPivot (V2) table?

Tags: excel-2010, powerpivot

What I have is:

A flat PowerPivot (V2) table to show the data as an ordinary Excel table (very much simplified, it's much wider):

|Starting date|Container|Color|Price|Price inc Tax|
|01.01.2009|container 240|blue|2,50 €|3,05 €|
|01.01.2009|container 240|red |3,60 €|4,39 €|
|01.01.2009|container 360|blue|4,20 €|5,12 €|

Might it be possible to format PowerPivot table so that the summarized columns are not in the end of a row? I'm trying to make a price list/catalog tool. There are a lot of fields in the table and some are less important and I'd like them to be shown after the prices. Starting date, Container and Color are column labels and the Price and Price Tax are summarized data.

Narutally I can't move the summarized data from Value area to Row or Column area in the field list, but is there any other way to reorder the columns so that I get the summarized data e.g. in between Starting date and Container?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Its possible but not totally straightforward.

Writing a measure that returns text is easy for instance:

```
=VALUES(Table1[Container])
```

....will return the text from a Column called Container in 'Table1' but ONLY if the context which has been established means that there is only one value for container (VALUES returns a single column table of all values that haven't been filtered out by the current context).

To make this robust you would need to trap errors so your whole formula would look like:

```
=IF(COUNTROWS(VALUES(Table1[Container]))>1,BLANK(),VALUES(Table1[Container]))
```

Once perfected this measure can be place after the more important data.

HTH

Jacob